# How do you navigate back to a the blank route of parent component?

Tags: angular, angular-router

I've got a component, called `MeHomeComponent`, with several children. The URL to reach `MeHomeComponent` is something like `myapp.com/somestuff/me`.

`MeHomeComponent` has the following template:

```
<div>

<ul>
  <li><a routerLink="" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">Feed</a></li>
  <li><a routerLink="agents" routerLinkActive="active">My Agent Contacts</a></li>
  <li><a routerLink="jobposts" routerLinkActive="active">My Job Posts</a></li>
</ul>

</div>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And the routing looks like the following:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
      path: '',
      component: MeHomeComponent,
      children: [
        { path: '', component: MeFeedComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'agents', component: MeAgentsComponent },
        { path: 'jobposts', component: MePostsComponent },
    ],
  }
];
```

**The problem is**, when I click on <kbd>Feed</kbd> it takes me to the homepage of the app - `myapp.com`! It doesn't take me back to `myapp.com/somestuff/me`. I've also tried with `routerLink="../"` but I get the same result!

So my question is, what do I give to `routerLink` to make my app go back to the URL `myapp.com/something/me`?

Comment: You must be getting error in console. Else you won't redirect to that page. Have you checked console ?

Comment: use **window.history.back();** its take to back to the page

Comment: @TheDictator not getting any error. It takes me cleanly to `myapp.com`

Comment: @Chandru that won't work. What if user clicks the other buttons a few times first? Then back will not take them to the component root

Comment: @CodyBugsteincan you try and enable tracing and check for the logs